# NSTableview showing a parenthese instead of array contents - Cocoa Bindings

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I have an array IgnoreAppsExpiryDates. I'm using a macro so it's called kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey in the code.

I'm adding strings to the array that represents dates:

> ```
>     if (timeLimitDays)
>    {
>        [IgnoreHelper addIgnoreTimeLimitForApp:timeLimitDays >forIgnore:appInfo.path];
>        let expiryDate = [IgnoreHelper getTimeLimitForAppIgnore:appInfo.path];
>        let expiry = expiryDate ? expiryDate.shortDateString : @"N/A".localized;
>       
>        kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey.defaultArray = [kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey.defaultArray arrayByAddingObject:expiry];
>
>   }
> ```

It's Objective-C. The let keyword is a macro for const __auto_type.

I use cocoa bindings to connect the array to a tableview column.
I have an array controller, I named it like the array: IgnoreAppsExpiryDates. I bind it to shared user defaults.
The model key path is my array with dates: IgnoreAppsExpiryDates

[image]

I then bind the array controller to the tableview column:

[image: Column binding]

But while the array contains NSStrings, the tableview only shows a parenthese.
Any ideas what I'm overlooking?

Edit:
Added info about the other array.

An other array is called kIgnoreAppsKey.
The array controller binded to kIgnoreAppsKey is called IgnoreAppsArray. It's an array with NSStrings that are paths.

[image]

The tableview has another column. I binded it to the IgnoreAppsArray. And it just works.
[image]

Both the arrays are set like this:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    NSMutableDictionary *defaultValues = makeMutableDictionary();
    defaultValues[kIgnoreAppsKey] = @[];
    defaultValues[kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey] = @[];
```

---

Writing to NSUserDefaults like this:

```
kIgnoreAppsKey.defaultArray = [kIgnoreAppsKey.defaultArray arrayByAddingObject:appInfo.path];
...
kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey.defaultArray = [kIgnoreAppsExpiryDatesKey.defaultArray arrayByAddingObject:expiry];


- (void)setDefaultArray:(NSArray *)newDefault
{
    assert(userDefaults);
    [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:newDefault forKey:self];
}
```

I don't understand why one array works and the other doesn't.

Comment: The *description* of an array starts with an open parenthesis. Obviously you bind `arrangedObjects` to an object which expects a single String. Usually an array of dictionaries is used or a custom class and a property or dictionary key is bound to *Model Key Path*

Comment: Is the table view view based or cell based?

Comment: It's cell based. |


@vadian
So if I add a dictionary like this:
NSDictionary *expiryDict = @{@"date": expiry};

and then Model Key Path: date.

It should work?

Comment: Yes, it does. By the way it's highly recommended to use a view based table view.

Comment: It's not my app.
I'm getting:"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date." error now.

I'll need to brush up on my key value coding. It's been too long. But at least I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: I still don't get it. There is another column that is set up exactly like I'm describing here and that one works fine.

Comment: Is the other column in the same table view and is it using the same array controller? How do you write the array to user defaults? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Yes, other column in same tableview. Different array controller. I added more info.

Comment: Binding to multiple array controllers is not supported. Does the problem column work if you remove the binding of the working column?